Does the idea of a 'logical inevitability' make sense? (The context of the question has to do with work, leisure and utopia)
I am wondering how to challenge the following argument about the 'inevitability' of a Utopia of leisure. The argument seems to rely on a somehow inflated view of what can be demonstrated by logic:
"[Bernard] Suits argues that a post-labor Utopia is “logically inevitable” (Suits, 1984b, p. 15). Humans have no choice in this matter because Utopia is the logical conclusion of their non-Utopian cultivation of work and engagement in instrumental action. For Suits, if humans work to avoid having to work, then given an infinite amount of time, they will ultimately arrive at a situation where no work is left to be done." (1)
Surely, while it is a fact about language that work and leisure are contraries, this does not tell us anything about the 'inevitability' of any state of affairs in the future. However, I am finding it hard to explain this clearly and put my finger on what kind of fallacy this involves. It seems to involve a kind of inflation of logical/linguistic facts into metaphysical/natural laws.
Can anyone think of other examples of this kind of argument and criticisms thereof? Can you help me better formulate my criticisms?
(1) From p. 23 of the introduction to:
Suits, B. (2023). Return of the Grasshopper: Games, Leisure and the Good Life in the Third Millennium (C. C. Yorke & F. J. L. Frías, Eds.). Routledge. https://doi.org/10.4324/9781003262398:

"given an infinite amount of time", no universe, no humans... And thus no work at all. This is not "logic".

There are so many problems with this, from the implication of the future eternity of time, to existence perpetual action which is tied to the the idea that every or nearly every possibility or potentiality will be exhausted and actualized given enough time but no such thing can be demonstrated, etc. A lot of assumptions....

By LEM the logical inevitability of work to avoid work is that one can not work to avoid work...

I am working only from the text you have quoted, not from the original. The argument presented is pretty weak. Here are a few observations.

Work and leisure are usually considered to be opposed, but many people enjoy their work and many people succeed in making a good living out of their leisure activities. For many, their work is part and parcel of how they define themselves, and life would be unfulfilling without it.

Even if we allow that for a lot of people work is something that gets in the way of leisure and they would avoid work if they could, it does not follow that repeated attempts to avoid work are bound to succeed. For one thing, there is no such thing as an infinite amount of time. As far as our best scientific theories are concerned, the universe will end in a heat death or a big rip and will be unable to support life. Also, if something is a practical impossibility, no amount of time will guarantee that it will happen. You may spend an unlimited amount of time trying to create a perpetual motion machine, but you won't succeed.

Human beings have continuing physical needs that require work to satisfy them. There is no such thing as a situation in which no work is left to be done. Maybe we could build robots to harvest food and recycle waste, and other robots to service those robots, and other robots to service those. But it seems highly unlikely that humans would become completely redundant. And if they did, maybe the robots would be smart enough to realise this and take over. That's a common enough theme in science fiction.

It is unsatisfactory to extrapolate past trends. Many people in the modern world enjoy much more leisure than in times past because energy is cheap and because machines have replaced slaves and beasts of burden. In the remote past, the cheapest source of abundant energy arose from growing crops, which were used to feed slaves and animals to provide leisure for others. The history of civilisation is partly the history of energy. (See, for example, Energy and Civilization: A History by Vaclav Smil.) We learned to use wood, then coal, then oil, and then nuclear energy, and in consequence our prosperity and leisure time increased. But the energy return on energy invested that we are now getting is no longer increasing as it did in the past. So it is unsafe to assume that our leisure will continue to increase. If anything, it is reasonable to predict a decline based on the depletion of readily available resources and a desire to move away from fossil fuels.


